# Ag-Grid: is it possible to style a row on a timer, instead of based on data in the row?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I need to change the background color of a row after a certain amount of time. There’s a column in the grid with a time in seconds, and I need to change the row color after 50% of that time has passed.

The data in the grid itself isn’t changing, so using rowClassRules doesn’t seem like it would work, as there’d be no change to trigger evaluating the data against a rule. I instead thought of using a setTimeout() function with a delay, but can’t figure out what would go inside of the setTimeout block to apply the css class to the rowNode. I don’t want to have to change any data in the row itself. Worse case scenario, I guess I could add a new hidden column and change a value in that column after the timer, but I’d prefer to avoid that. I am using React.

I tried doing something like this:

```
let red_warnings = [] 

let yellow_warnings = []
```

```
const rowClassRules = {
    '.red': (params) => { return red_warnings.includes(params.data.Id) }, 
    '.yellow': (params) => { return yellow_warnings.includes(params.data.Id) } 
}

<AgGridReact
    rowClassRules={rowClassRules}
/>
```

```
// when a new row is added
setTimeout(() => {
    yellow_warnings.push(Id)
}, 1000 * Timeout * 0.5)

setTimeout(() => {
    red_warnings.push(Id)
}, 1000 * Timeout * 0.8)
```

but since there's no data actually being changed in the row, there's nothing to trigger the rowClassRules being re-evaluated once I add the ID into the warnings array.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible.

*The idea is to update grid data to apply some pre-defined styles.*

For instance, we update age field as 100 for each record after 3 seconds. According to our rowClassRules, any data in which age is bigger than 98 will be a candidate to our pre-defined styles.

```
function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    params.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      var newData = {
        ...node.data,
        person: {
          ...node.data.person,
          age: 100,
        },
      }
      node.data = newData
      params.api.redrawRows()
    })
  }, 3000)
}
```

Take a look at this plunker

https://plnkr.co/plunk/wVt8QvavUM1UrblC